# timestamp fields on Laravel 5 alway return year only

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.0.28
When I create a new user, the created_at and updated_at alway 2015.
How can I fix it?

Comment: How did you created the migration or db?

Comment: I migrate db the first time by comand: ./artisan migrate:install and I got migrations, migration, user table with user.created_at and user.updated_at  field type are int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use that line in model? And set the table field type datetime

```
public $timestamps = true;
```

Comment: After change these field type to timestamp, they run well. After make migration, I saw that in user table have 2 field: created_at and updated_at with field type is int. I used to use timestamp as int so I think everything ok. I'm very confuse about timestamp and int, would you please clarify it?

Comment: if you use field type timestamp,the field store data as date time,but if use int it will store data as integer type.